# Listar metodos de control con TypeConverter

Tags: c#, windows-forms

buen día, a ver si me pueden dar una mano, tengo el siguiente control personalizado:

```
> public class TextBoxCustom : System.Windows.Form.TextBox {
>     [TypeConverter(typeof(MetodoBusquedaTypeConverter))]
>     public string Metodos {get; set;}
> 
>     public void Lista()
>     {
>         // CODE
>     }
> 
>     public void Renueva()
>     {
>         // CODE
>     }
> 
>     public void Etc()
>     {
>         // CODE
>     } }
```

La idea es que la propiedad Métodos permita seleccionar de entre todos los métodos que tenga el control TextBoxCustom (es decir, Lista, Renueva, Etc, ...)
Aquí el TypeConverter:

```
> public class MetodoBusquedaTypeConverter : TypeConverter {
>     public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
>     {
>         return true;
>     }
> 
>     public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext)
>     {
>         return true;
>     }
> 
>     public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext)
>     {
>         List<string> values = new List<string>();
>         
>         // AQUI CON REFLEXION DEBERIA ACCEDER A LAS PROPIEDADES DE CONTROL AL QUE PERTENECE LA PROPIEDAD, PERO NO SE COMO HACERLO
>         
>         values.Sort();
>         
>         return new StandardValuesCollection(values);
>     } }
```

Bueno gracias desde ya con cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dices puedes usar **Reflexion** y combinarlo con **Linq** y tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
var metodos = MyObject.GetType().GetMethods().Select(m => m.Name).ToList();
```

Aquí guardamos en la **variable metodos** los nombres de todos los métodos que tiene el objeto **MyObject**(en tu ejemplo tendrá otro nombre).

Accedemos a los métodos de un objeto primeramente a través del **método** **GetType**, el cual nos devuelve el tipo del objeto y posteriormente invocamos el **método** **GetMethods** para obtener todos los métodos y por último aplicamos un **select**, para obtener solamente el nombre de los métodos, obteniendo de esta forma una lista de **string**, donde cada elemento de esta lista sería el nombre de un método del objeto analizado.

**Mucho cuidado**, debes tener en cuenta que si tu clase **hereda** de otra, también se mostrarán los métodos que pertenecen a la clase padre, y también recuerda que en **C#** todas las clases heredan de la clase **Object**, y esta posee **4** métodos:

**Equals**

**GetHashCode**

**GetType**

**ToString**

Y si además, en tu clase tienes **propiedades** de tipo **get/set**, como por ejemplo:

```
public string Nombre { get; set; }
```

Esto se traduce por el compilador por dos métodos individuales

**get_Nombre**

**set_Nombre**

Por lo que por cada propiedad que tengas tendrás dos métodos.

**Resumiendo:**

Al obtener los métodos de tu clase obtendrás los métodos propios de esta:

**Lista**

**Renueva**

**Etc**

Y obtendrás todos los métodos de las clases padres de las que hereda tu clase, incluyendo la **clase** **Object**, que es la principal en la **jerarquía de clases** de **C#**, y si además, tienes propiedades por cada una de ellas obtendrás dos métodos, un **método get** y otro **método set**.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, el problema que tengo es que no sé como acceder al objeto desde el método GetStandardValues de MetodoBusquedaTypeConverter. El método GetStandardValues solo tiene el parámetro pContext (desde el cual no puedo acceder al objeto que contiene la propiedad). Saludos.

Comment: Crea otro parametro y pasale por ahi el objeto, puedes hacerlo de mil maneras, de verdad que no entiendo tu problema

Comment: La lista de valores se llena en el método sobreescrito GetStandardValues (de la clase MetodoBusquedaTypeConverter), no se puede agregar otro parámetro porque el método base solo tiene 1 parámetro (ITypeDescriptorContext pContext). Ahora si hago pContext.GetType() me retorna System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.PropertyDescriptorGridEntry (cuando lo que yo necesito es que me retorne TextBoxCustom)

Comment: Es que tu disenno de clases lo veo raro, pero bueno puedes tener en tu clase MetodoBusquedaTypeConverter un constructor que reciba como parametro un objeto de tipo TextBoxCustom

Comment: Y dentro de la clase MetodoBusquedaTypeConverter  tendrias un campo privado de tipo TextBoxCustom , que capturara el valor del objeto TextBoxCustom pasado por parametro al constructor

Comment: Entiendo lo que me dices, lo que no entiendo es como darle funcionalidad para que trabaje en conjunto con el TypeConverter, debido a que MetodoBusquedaTypeConverter sera usado como atributo de una propiedad de mi control personalizado TextBoxCustom .

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127511/discussion-between-japv-and-pedropg).